# AMQP or XMPP for Client Notifications

Tags: java, javascript, c#, xmpp, amqp

I'm designing a replacement for a custom messaging system that is currently used to notify a JavaScript web application about changed content from the server side (Java). This legacy messaging system works through Flash XMLSocket by use of custom text based protocol and plain Java sockets.

The replacement will be used not only by the web application (through web sockets instead of Flash) but by an additional desktop client application written in C# too.

My requirements are:

- user authentication
- transport encryption (SSL/TLS)
- bidirectional message exchange
- some sort of (automatic) publish/subscribe so that users get only the messages they are allowed to receive
- message exchange based on an established protocol (so that we may use existing libraries where possible)
- cluster-able server components

At this time the messaging system will only be used to publish updates down to the clients. The clients will react to these messages and acquire further information directly from the server (not via the messaging system). If this new messaging system is established successfully it may be used for more advanced use cases in the future. Some possibilities may include users chatting, file exchange and remote control of the server components.

I did a little research about viable technology to implement these requirements and I think my choices boil down to either using [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) (XMPP) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (AMQP). What are the main pros and cons of these two systems regarding my requirements? We already use RabbitMQ for other parts of our system infrastructure so it was my natural choice. I'm just not sure if it would be a good idea to have client applications connect directly to such an critical main component. This may be mitigated though by just using a different RabbitMQ installation for the client notifications.

Comment: If you're still using Java then J2EE JMS may be an option or SonicMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could use both protocols to fulfill your needs, xmpp is an extensible protocol so no doubt the things that you're looking for does allready exist as a `plugin` or whatever is the correct term for a protocol. However some, me included, might actually see this as a downside, and they add extra complexity to the protocol. Another thing to keep in mind is that xmpp was primarily designed to be a instant messaging protocol. For example publish/subscribe is an [extension](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html) of xmpp and not part of the protocol itself.

That being said xmpp is backed by organisations such as Google, which means that there are some major players using this protocol, so no doubt some of the extensions are really good and well written/thought out.

On the other hand you have AMQP, a protocol almost specifically designed for what you're after. It is backed by such organisations as JP Morgan, Cisco, Credit Suisse etc. so no doubt AMQP is a protocol to be counted on, even though early versions of it has been [critized](http://www.imatix.com/articles:whats-wrong-with-amqp)

When it comes to using RabbitMQ there seem to be some issues with [memory](https://www.google.se/#hl=sv&sclient=psy-ab&q=RAbbit%20MQ%20memory%20spikes&fp=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b), however I cannot speak much of that since I was only notified about this issue, and never really got into actually fix it or even understand it. However there seem to be quite a few people experiencing this on different versions of RMQ.

But for me RabbitMQ has never crashed (hey if erlang is known for one thing, it's stability), it has been a joy to setup and it is really easy to setup in a cluster, and you can have your queues easily mirrored on several instances of RMQ and you can have an extra layer of security by having one or more instances write messages to disk.

So I'd say go with RabbitMQ and AMQP, I believe it's a protocol well suited for your needs, but having said that xmpp could probably do the work just fine aswell.

I've read [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182978), which is a nice introduction to AMQP and RabbitMQ but I find it lacking in the technical aspect, it's basically a good tutorial.

PS: I feel I should be honest and say that I'm not really sure what `bidirectional message exchange` entails, but if it means sending and receiving messages, you're in the clear on that point also with AMQP. :)

I hope this helped shed some light on which protocol to choose.

**Edit**

RabbitMQ has something called `virtual hosts` which acts like an own instance of RabbitMQ so you don't have to start with setting up a cluster just to handle separate responsibilities. Depending on how you set up your queues and exchanges I don't see a problem with clients connecting to the RabbitMQ server, but clustering is without a doubt a good idea. It also seems that setting up RabbitMQ with HAProxy is very easy, but yet again that is something I have no experience of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how easy is it to get RabbitMQ to do user authentication against our application database? Is it even a sound idea to want to do that or should I look into other patterns of setting up authentication?

Comment: Okay I've must have missunderstood you a bit, the authentication is for the applications wanting to access Rabbit. What RabbitMQ does, is to send messages, and it's really good at sending messages. So in this case you would send a message to an application which in turn queries the database, based on information in the message.

Comment: I guess this may be possible.

Comment: I have to disagree with some of your opinions on XMPP. You say that pubsub, for instance,  is not part of the protocol, that it is an extension. XMPP was actually designed for this purpose, as the X actually stands for eXtensible. The protocol consists of a specification for basic message exchange as well as a variety of specifications to address specific functional use cases for message passing.  Pubsub would be one of these, multi-user chat for instance is another.  You imply that they are basically afterthoughts, that don't actually belong to protocol which is not the case.

Comment: @Robin There is no doubt that xmpp was designed to be extensible, I state that in the first sentence of my answer. But there is also no denying that pub/sub is an extension and not part of the core protocol. The mere fact that I state that I and some others see this as a downside, implies that others (maybe you?) don't. I also state in the second paragraph that many protocol extensions undoubtedly are of very high quality, so I don't really understand you criticism. Unless it's because of the order of the two last sentences in the first paragraph, if thats the case why not suggest an edit?